# How to include Sensor logo in MDPI LaTeX template?

Tags: journal-publishing, journal, mdpi

I used the MDPI Latex package from https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex, once I open it in Overleaf I can't see the sensor logo there ( top left side ). Is there any way to include that in Overleaf ?

here is my paper in overleaf :
[image]

Here is another paper, where I want to have like this logo.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that defines the part of the template with the logo can be found in the file `mdpi.cls` (inside the directory `Definitions`). There you will find the following lines (which you also posted as image to your question):

```
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
    \begin{flushleft}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@arttype}{Supfile}}{%
        \fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont
        \raggedright
        \hyphenpenalty=10000
        \tolerance=1000
        \noindent\textbf{Supplementary Materials: \@Title}%
        \par
        \vspace{12pt}
        \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
        \noindent\boldmath\bfseries{\@Author}
        }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@arttype}{Book}}{}{%
            \vspace*{-1.75cm}
            }
        {%0
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@journal}{preprints}
            \OR \equal{\@arttype}{Book}}{}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@status}{submit}}{% 
                    \hfill \href{https://www.mdpi.com}{%
                    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{Definitions/logo-mdpi.eps}}%
                    }{
                    \href{https://www.mdpi.com/journal/\@journal}{
                    \includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{Definitions/\@journal-logo.eps}}%
                    \hfill
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@journal}{scipharm}}{%
                        \href{https://www.mdpi.com}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{Definitions/logo-mdpi-scipharm.eps}}%
                        }{%
                        \href{https://www.mdpi.com}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{Definitions/logo-mdpi.eps}}%
                        }%
                    }%
                    \par
                    \vspace{-8 pt}
                    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
            }%
        \par
        }%0
        {%1
            \vspace{14pt}
            \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@arttype}{Book}}{}{
            \textit{\@arttype}%
            }%  
        \par%
            }%1
            {%2
     %  \vspace{8pt}
        \fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont
        \hyphenpenalty=10000
        \tolerance=1000
        \boldmath\bfseries{\@Title}
        \par
        \vspace{16pt}
        }%2
        {%3
        \hyphenpenalty=10000
        \tolerance=1000
            \boldmath\bfseries{\@Author}
            \par
        \vspace{-1pt}
            }%3
        }
    \end{flushleft}%
    }
```

The easiest way to include your other logo here would be to replace these two lines (lines 683 and 684 in the file)

```
\hfill \href{https://www.mdpi.com}{%
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{Definitions/logo-mdpi.eps}}%
```

by this

```
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo-sensor.png} \hfill \href{https://www.mdpi.com}{%
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{Definitions/logo-mdpi.eps}}%
```