# MDPI Informatics logo positioning

Tags: positioning, mdpi

Iam trying to start decorating my MDPI LATEX template for my thesis journal. The initial template has only the mdpi logo on top right. I want to place the Informatics logo on top left.
This is what i want[image: This is what i like]. This is what i have [image: This is what I have]

This is the logo [image]

Here you can download the appropriate files https://www.mdpi.com/data/MDPI_template.zip?v=20220713

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625831/how-to-include-sensor-logo-in-mdpi-latex-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question which handles the same issue here [How to include Sensor logo in MDPI LaTeX template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625831/how-to-include-sensor-logo-in-mdpi-latex-template). Take care to add includegraphics befor includegraphichs mdpi.eps

Answer (score 0):

Without editing the class: put the logo named `logo-informatics.png` in the directory `Definitions` and add after `\documentclass[journal,article,submit,pdftex,moreauthors]{Definitions/mdpi}` :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\hfill \href{https://www.mdpi.com}}
{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{Definitions/logo-informatics}\hfill \href{https://www.mdpi.com}}
{}{}
\makeatother
```

Compile with `pdflatex`.

[image: a]

Comment: thank you very much